# Ionic 3 calling didExitRegion() randomly

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, exit, region, beacon

Currently using the iBeacon plugin.

My devices enter the region regularly and stay within range. But over some random amount of time. Exit Region is called. Leaving my device not being able to log back in and waiting on a random time to log in again.

```
let delegate = this.ibeacon.Delegate();

delegate.didRangeBeaconsInRegion().subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log('Beacon Found:  ', data.beacons.length);
      if(data.beacons.length > 0) {
        this.services.currentBeacon.uuid = data.beacons[0].uuid;
        this.services.currentBeacon.major = data.beacons[0].major;
        this.services.currentBeacon.minor = data.beacons[0].minor;

        this.ibeacon.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion);


        this.services.GetBeacon(data.beacons[0].major, data.beacons[0].minor).subscribe(
          data => {
            ...
          }
        );
      }
    },
    error => console.error()
  );
delegate.didEnterRegion().subscribe(
    data => {
      //console.log('didEnterRegion: ', data);
      //this.services.postMessage(1, 'Alert', "Entered Beacon region");
      this.ibeacon.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion);
    }
  );

  delegate.didExitRegion().subscribe(
    data => {
      //this.services.postMessage(1, 'Alert', "Exited Beacon Region");
    }
  );
```

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.12
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.5.0
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
ios-deploy        : 1.9.2 
Node              : v8.9.4
npm               : 5.6.0 
OS                : macOS High Sierra
Xcode             : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : /Users/rflores2/Library/Android/sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

dependencies:
    "@ionic-native/ibeacon": "^4.5.3",

Comment: "randomly" exiting the region is a common problem that can have many causes.  The core issue is always that the beacon is not detected by the phone for a long period of time.  It may help to find a solution to know the operating system version you are using and whether bringing the app to he foreground causes you to enter the region again.

Comment: david, foreground and background does not affect the device finding the beacon again. Both have exited in the same way.